# problem with python3 flask app executed with mode wsgi on apache2/windows

Tags: python, windows, mod-wsgi, mysql-connector

I have a flask app that works when started on standalone mode (main.py) with python 3.8. When I start it on mode wsgi (main.wsgi) on apache2/windows, the app starts but crashes with this error in apache2 logs :

```
from mysql.connector import *
AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'CMySQLConnection'
```

What can explain this difference of behavior between two identical codes ?

My Apache2 Virtual host :

```
define ROOT "C:/Data/st-2020/dev/python/cours-2020/v01-deployment/flask"
define SITE "impots"

 <VirtualHost *:80> 
    WSGIScriptAlias /app "${ROOT}/mainWithMySQL.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache2 httpd.conf:

```
# python wsgi
LoadFile "c:/myprograms/python38/python38.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/myprograms/python38/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/myprograms/python38"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
from mysql.connector import *
```

I had to rewrite it as:

```
from mysql.connector import connect
```

I don't know why.